# Why is it displaying posts after the loop?

Tags: wordpress, owl-carousel

Hello all I'm building a post slider for a client and Im having some issues, the slider displays fine nothing wrong with that, its just displaying the posts from the category after the loop, and Im not sure why, its not the page template as when I remove this shortcode it disappears ?

My code is

```
    function post_slider( $atts ){
    $a = shortcode_atts( array(
           'category' => 'something',
    ), $atts );

    query_posts('category_name=' . $a['category']);
    ?>
        <div id="owl-example" class="owl-carousel">
            <?php
            while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                <div class="postSlide" style="padding: 20px">
                    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                    <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                    <p><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read More</a></p>
                </div>
            <?php
            endwhile;
            ?>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
    add_shortcode( 'post_slider', 'post_slide' );

    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_js' );

    function add_js() {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'custom_scripts', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/scripts-min.js', array ( 'jquery' ), true);
    }

    function new_excerpt_length($length) {
    return 25;
    }
    add_filter('excerpt_length', 'new_excerpt_length');
```

How it displays:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, add `wp_reset_query();` after your `endwhile;` to stop it from displaying posts after :)